# GWT getting image from database using RPC and display it in the UI

Tags: gwt, upload

I am trying to make an image uploading widget and store the image in the GWT database so it can be read from it later. Here's the code:

Servlet (HttpServletRequest request)

```
/*   */

    iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    FileItemStream item = iter.next();
                    InputStream stream = item.openStream();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    int len;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                    while ((len = stream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                    Blob content = new Blob(out.toByteArray());

/*    */
```

Entity

```
    public class ImageEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated
    private Blob image;
/*    */
```

RCP implementation

```
/*    */

    public String getImageData(Long id){  
        EntityManager em = EMF.get();
        jtwitter.shared.Image image = em.find(jtwitter.shared.Image.class, id);
        Blob blobData = image.getImage();
        System.out.println(blobData.getBytes().length);;
        byte[] imageData = image.getImage().getBytes();
        System.out.println(imageData.length);
        String base64 = Base64Utils.toBase64(imageData);
        base64 = "data:image/png;base64,"+ base64;  
        return base64;  
    } 
public String getImageData(Long id){  
        EntityManager em = EMF.get();
        jtwitter.shared.Image image = em.find(jtwitter.shared.Image.class, id);
        Blob blobData = image.getImage();
        System.out.println(blobData.getBytes().length);;
        byte[] imageData = image.getImage().getBytes();
        System.out.println(imageData.length);
        String base64 = Base64Utils.toBase64(imageData);
        base64 = "data:image/png;base64,"+ base64;  
        return base64;  
    }
/*    */
```

On the client side I'm calling com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image img = new Image(*getImageData's result*). All I get is a broken image icon, right clicking on it gives image code in bytes. I've tried comparing sizes and original image size is same as the one read inside the getImageData's method.

Thanks for reading,
P.

Comment: That's all very interesting, but what is your question?

Comment: How to not get a broken image I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using bad implementation of a B64. For some reason beyond me the actualy B64 supplied by com.google.appengine.api doesn't work with the apache uploader. Instead you should use this http://iharder.net/base64

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
HTML html = new HTML("<img src=\""+getImageData's result+"\" alt=\"Foo\">");
```

Or have you tried with other B64 util class?

Other option is generate a url from your DB and pass it to your image instead of all the B64 data (we are doing this and it works well).

Thanks,

Adolfo.

Comment: Actually it was the B64 problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why you want to create your own upload widget and not use a library like [gwtupload](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) which gives you many things out-of-the-box.

Anyway, and related with your question about how to get the saved image in the ddbb, I would never use RPC to get the image and show it in the UI, but a servlet to return the binary image, which has been the normal way for ages.

Using RPC has many caveats:

- You have to convert images to base-64 strings, which increases a lot the size
- RPC mechanism has to deal with large strings in both client and server sides, penalizing the performance (serialization/deserialization, escaping, memory issues, etc).
- RCP is not cacheable, so the client is going to download always the image

I think this is not in your query, but if you wanted the image in b64 in client you can do it in any browser supporting canvas.

In summary, I would follow the DRY principle with gwtupload: Using `SingleUploader` or `MultipleUploader` in client, extending `UploadAction` in server, and overriding `executeAction()` to save uploaded files to the DDBB and  `getUploadedFile()` to get the file back.

Comment: I was running into a deadline with the other method so I didn't really try any other ones. But you got me curious, is there any step by step guide to the loading images with servlet?

Comment: The gwtupload [getting-started](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted) guide is very easy to follow. Following the examples it uploads images and saves them in disk, maintaining a list in memory. The client shows those images. The only thing you have to do is to change is the code to save your files.